# Borsh, pubkey & COption

Tags: solana-sdk, borsh

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub struct Mint_instruction_data {
    pub tag: u8,
    pub decimals: u8,
    pub mint_authority: Pubkey,
    pub freeze_authority: COption<Pubkey>, 
}
```

This doesn't compile and is giving me the following error for both Pubkey and COption

```
  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Pubkey: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:61:10
   |
61 | #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `Pubkey`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
             &T
             ()
             (T0, T1)
             (T0, T1, T2)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
             (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)
           and 67 others
   = help: see issue #48214
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `BorshSerialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error. Are you using the solana cli tools edge build?
I am, because I couldn't get dependencies satisfied with the stable build.

Comment: nope, just cargo. but i found this https://docs.rs/spl-token-2022/0.6.1/spl_token_2022

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think that's a part of the problem. I'm not using that library in my program and I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: I am getting the same issue @JorgeMartinez did you solve this ?

Comment: Yeah I was able to solve it by downgrading borsh to 0.9.3. But more importantly, make sure that the version of solana that you are working with matches what the solana project repo is using as Jon C mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In my Cargo.toml I was using borsh=0.10.3 and downgrading to borsh=0.9.3 fixed my problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer -- the current Solana crates derive `BorshSerialize` and `BorshDeserialize` on version 0.9 of Borsh, which is incompatible with version 0.10. This will be enabled in version 1.16 of the Solana crates with https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/30975